# How to superimpose a GridLayout on a ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, grid-layout, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe on android just for fun, and I don't know how to design it. In fact, i made a Grid Layout to have 9 interactiv squares but I don't know how to put the grid's picture under it.

First I put the grid on the background attribute:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/Game"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:numColumns="3"

    android:background="@drawable/grid"
    >
```

But it didn't work :

Then i tried to put an Imageview as a parent of the gridLayout but it's impossible. Is there an other way ?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of the gridLayout or table layout is that you setup the grid as you've done and then you add child components for each grid element.  In the case of your TicTacToe board, I'd suggest you added 9 ImageButtons, one for each box.  When the user clicks on the button, you can change the image from blank to either a X or O.

This is an example I pulled from a dialed, which has a similar grid/table concept.

```
       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_dtmf_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_dial_1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dialer_button_1" />
```

In the java code, you'll identify each of the 9 ImageButtons and set a click listener to each of them.

Here are the basics of the GridLayout:  http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Comment: ok for the image buttons, but now how can I put this grid under the image buttons ? src :https://github.com/tomgiraudet/tictactoc/blob/master/Gam%27Insa/img/Grid.png

Comment: The ImageButtons are likely obscuring the background of the GridLayout.  You can try setting margins or padding on each of the buttons to provide space for the background to show.